# Is there any function .AddParameterWithValue() in php like it is in asp?

Tags: php, asp.net, function, high-availability

I was searching over the internet to simplify my query strings, I found a function in ASP.NET and was thinking that is there any function `.AddParameterWithValue()` in php as well?

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: Is call_user_func or call_user_func_array what you are looking for?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are actually looking for? Keeping things in secret does not really help to answer a question...

Comment: I am not hiding anything, I just wanted to know that is there a function like that in PHP as well so that I can simplify my query :) JUST THAT.

Comment: In ASP when we write a query, we give it some keywords like `@username` or @password` and then with `AddParameterWithValue()` we give those keywords some value and they get intergrated into our query automatically so is there any like in PHP?